Migrating Firebase Auth data to another project loses Google provider info
After i imported the auth data, the provider is empty and the identifier becomes (anonymous).
My user provider only uses Google Play Games and Game Center.
This is how i do the migration:

Use Firebase CLI to export authentication data, the command is as follows:
firebase auth:export auth_data.json --format=json


Then I switch to another firebase project and import:
firebase auth:import auth_data.json



But in firebase auth user list, the provider is empty and the identifier becomes (anonymous)
Then I try to export the data again and re-import, all the authentication data becomes (anonymous).
Sample JSON after i exported:
"localId": "XXXXXX",
"displayName": "XXXX",
"lastSignedInAt": "XXXX",
"createdAt": "XXXXX",
"providerUserInfo": []

Data exported the data after reimported:
"user": [ { "localId": "XXXXXX", "emailVerified": XXXXXX, "displayName": "XXXXXX",
"photoUrl": "XXXXXX", "lastSignedInAt": "XXXXXX", "createdAt": "XXXXXX", "disabled": false }, 

Is there any way to recover my user data? or correct way to do the migration?
I have tried export to csv and import again, it wont update/recover the auth data anymore.
